# Excel 2016 Web Query Script Error Line 0 Char 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, import

While trying to start a basic web query on any yahoo finance or msnmoney web page I get the following error right off the bat.

[image: Error shown in excel browser when navigating to any site.]

Any ideas? I am running Windows 10 and Excel 2016.
PS: I know this is not a lot to go on but hopefully someone has seen this error before and can help me out.

Comment: Where does this error come from? You haven't shown us any of your work. Upload an image and cut/paste as a modified block of code so we can gauge what you are doing please. I could conjecture many things and be 100% wrong because I don't know what you did to get this error. Accessing a js file? Trying to copy a js file? You create a js file and uploaded it or using a js file to query something? See what I mean?

Comment: I do see what you mean. I am using the built in new web query button, located under the 'Data' tab, in 'Get External Data' group, then clicking 'From Web'. Then the excel browser pops up and after that this error. Tried this on multiple computers to the same result. Hope that helps. Since asking this I have decided to just go with google sheets which is built better in my opinion for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and it turned out to be a corruption of the NTFS permissions in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer. There are several possible system corruptions that can cause this problem, and they are well covered at [a Stack Overflow answer about localStorage objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331783/ie-11-office-js-access-is-denied-trying-to-use-localstorage)

Coming from Excel, this is probably a corruption may be an incorrect integrity level in %userprofile%\Appdata\LocalLow, which affects the DOMStore at %userprofile%\Appdata\LocalLow\Microsoft Internet Explorer, where the DOMStore (localStorage) lives.

There is also a possible registry corruption issues, covered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102116/access-denied-for-localstorage-in-ie10/23583134#23583134